# How to encode strings in R with double backslashes?

Tags: r, string, encode

Is there any easy way in R to encode strings with double backslashes?. I extracted some data from a website and realised that words in the data were decoded. The following is part of the data:

```
'"option_name\":\"\\uc81c\\ud488\\uc120\\ud0dd#$%\\uc0c9\\uc0c1\"'
```

I want it to be:

```
'"option_name":"제품선택#$%색상"'
```

If I manually replace double backslashes from the string and print, it works fine but I want to avoid manual work with this. It would be great if someone could help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Given the example provided, it does not appear to have "double backslashes" -- perhaps you mean double quotes?

In either case, the string on the right of the colon is in Unicode, so something like this will encode correctly:

```
string <- "\uc81c\ud488\uc120\ud0dd#$%\uc0c9\uc0c1"
new_string <- enc2utf8(string)
cat(new_string)
"제품선택#$%색상"
```

If you want to treat the entire selection as one string, you can wrap it in single quotes:

```
string <- '"option_name":"\uc81c\ud488\uc120\ud0dd#$%\uc0c9\uc0c1"'
new_string <- enc2utf8(string)
cat(new_string)    
"option_name":"제품선택#$%색상"

# to remove the double quotes at the same time:
new_string <- gsub('\"', "", enc2utf8(string))
cat(new_string)
option_name:제품선택#$%색상
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply but my string does have double backslashes. My example string is as follows: string <-'"option_name\":\"\\uc81c\\ud488\\uc120\\ud0dd#$%\\uc0c9\\uc0c1\"' and this does not encoded with the enc2utf8 function.